# htaccess hotlink protection

Tags: .htaccess

So I'm trying to protect FLV files using htaccess.

Basically I want to block direct access to the .flv (so blank referrer) and block hotlinking from any website that isn't my own.

I'm doing this from a WordPress install but it's not on the root, it's in a subdirectory. so mydomain.com/test/videos/

I've tried the following code but I am still able to type a direct filename of the flv and chrome will download the file, so it isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/videos/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.co.uk(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(flv)$ templates/images/logo.jpg [L,NC]
```

Any ideas where this is going wrong? it doesn't return a server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    RewriteEngine on    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.co.uk/test/videos [NC]
    RewriteRule \.(flv)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still allows direct access when just typing in the URL.