# .htaccess provide access for html document only

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to deny direct access from browser to images folder.

I tried to include

```
Deny from  all
```

and

```
Options -Indexes
```

And it works good but the problem is the html file cannot see these folder as well. As a result, there is no images on the website.

How to provide access to this folder for html document

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do?  Do you intend to block requests to your images, _except when called from your webpage_? What you have done is block it entirely.  HTML files don't "see" folders, rather the browser requests the images.

Comment: You might find your answer here seems like the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600920/how-do-you-hide-the-folders-in-your-websites-public-html-folder

Comment: I think the OP is trying to prevent hotlinking, but I'm not certain.

Comment: If that is correct, the term to search is "hotlinking", such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378902/htaccess-hotlink-protection

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes. "Intend to block requests to your images, except when called from your webpage"

Comment: See [many of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prevent+hotlink)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Images referenced from an HTML document get requested by browsers the same way as if you'd put in the image URI into the address bar of the browser.

It's the same HTTP request (`GET /path/to/image HTTP/1.1`)

Comment: But you can inspect the referrer.

Comment: I think he was talking about disabling image list.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: But you can fake the referer easily.

Comment: How? How someone can fake referer in the user's browser?

Comment: @knittl Yep, hotlink protection (if that's what is even being asked) fails right about there.

Comment: @nick4fake The HTTP_REFERER header is sent by the client, and can therefore be faked however you like, and is sometimes not sent at all.

Comment: @nick4fake: you don't need a browser to generate HTTP requests. But I'm 100 % sure there's some browser plugins that allow you to manipulate request headers.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it is not possible to fake referer of remote browser. hotlink protection helps.

Comment: Guys, we were talking about hotlinking. it IS possible to prevent it with referer

Comment: Some restrictive proxies or firewalls might also strip the referer header from HTTP requests, so those users can't see the images either.

Comment: Generally, many sites use referers to check previous page (eg, google). So it is not bad practice.

Comment: @nick4fake: google's landing page does not even validate to w3c, so I'm not sure that "Google does it, that means it's not bad practice" is a valid claim. But that's OT and hasn't got anything to do with the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove "Deny from  all " option from .htaccess

You only need "Options -Indexes " to disable indexes